# Is it possible to incorporate user input controls into Android notifications?

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to include user input controls such as sliders, buttons, radio buttons, etc. into Android app notifications (lock screen notifications)?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have all widgets in notification.

Comment: What about standard actions?

Comment: "action" is not "widget". See documentation